# Can not create new route after adding Swagger Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, swagger

I've used this documentation https://codefactory.searchmymarket.com/install-swagger-in-laravel/ to create swagger documentation for all APIs in my Laravel project

The documentation works fine for already added APIs, but when I try to add new routes, even if they are Web routes, they are not displayed when I try to access their link using browser/Postman/Swagger , the new APIs are displayed in the Swagger documentation but if I try to access them, they give me error 404 like they never exists

I tried to use the command `php artisan route:list` to display list of routes in my project, but it does not show me my new routes like they never exists

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, it is only required to clear route cache using
`php artisan route:clear`